# show text in the right encoding in html

Tags: php, encoding, html-entities

I am trying to get some data(varchar) from my database and show them in my html in the right encoding because it contains german special characters.
The database is in latin1_german2_ci(cp1252), my html

```
<input type="text" id="owner" name="owner" value="<?=get_owner() ?>" class="form-control">
function get_owner()
{
    $owner = htmlentities($text_I_got_from_db, ENT_COMPAT, 'cp1252');
    return $owner;
}
```

This gives me, ie. `Kälte` in my `<input>`, but I want `K&auml;lte`. 
I know that `htmlentities()` turns special chars to htmlcode. How do I do that it stay that way in html and not "converted back"?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print text in page 'as is' you may use code like this

```
    $owner = htmlentities('Kälte', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    echo htmlspecialchars($owner);
```